# Sandbox modifies subject on email sent from trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am writing a trigger in a sandbox, and am sending an email through the sandbox. I've added a the Account Name to the Subject in my trigger.

When the email is sent from the trigger, Salesforce appends "Sandbox:" before the subject I wrote in apex.

Is there a way to remove the "Sandbox:" subject from emails send out of a sandbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a standard Salesforce functionality to Identity email send from Salesforce.

Once you send email from Production this Sandbox is automatically removed but in Sandbox this is not possible.